# Javascript - TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am writing a telemetry function in my code. I am using the Performance.getEntriesByType() function mentioned at the MDN link here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType.
As per the link it mentions that the method returns a list of PerformanceEntry objects / empty list.
However, when I invoke the "forEach" method on the returned value of the window.performance.getEntriesByType(type) method, I get the following error

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'
```

Couple of doubts:

1. Why do I get the error 'forEach' has no method?
2. What does Object [object Object] in the error message imply?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are attempting to invoke the `forEach()` method on an object that does not have `forEach()` method. `forEach()` is implemented on `Array.prototype` (meaning that all arrays have this method) and some browsers implement it on DOM `nodeList` objects. But, you are either trying to use it on another kind of object or in a browser that doesn't support it.

`performance.getEntriesByType()` returns a `list`, which is not the same thing as an `Array`, which is where `forEach()` is implemented.

**[The page you referenced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType)**, shows how you can loop through the resulting list from the `window.performance.getEntriesByType()` call.

```
  // Use getEntries() to iterate through the each entry
  var p = performance.getEntries();
  for (var i=0; i < p.length; i++) {
    log("Entry[" + i + "]");
    check_PerformanceEntry(p[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Any help on why I see the error as  Object [object Object]? Why the 3 object identifiers?

Comment: @Saint The default conversion of an object to a string is "[object Object]", so really you are just seeing the type of object you have an error with ("Object") and then the string representation of that, which shows it's underlying type as well ("[object Object]").

Answer (score 1):

I personally ran into a bug on an android device and the issue was in a dependency's code so I couldn't change it. I used [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) to fix the issue:

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (callback, thisArg) {
        thisArg = thisArg || window;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jlafay this polyfill made my Ionic 5 app work on my prehistoric Android 4.4 phone. I just had to change the way of checking if NodeList exists:

if (window.hasOwnProperty('NodeList') && !NodeList.prototype.forEach)